# Is it possible to load data into a plotly python graph?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Now the graph shows 3 values: X, Y and color(data_a). Is it possible to load data to such a chart (without drawing a chart based on new data)?

```
data_a = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
fig = px.imshow(xg, aspect="auto",color_continuous_scale='ice')
fig.show()

data_b = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
data_c = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
```

The task, when hovering over the graph, showed 5 values. Is this possible in plotly?

An example of a picture that I want to receive enter image description here:

[image]

Comment: According to documentation there is no such example, so I suppose it is not supported. Maybe you can create your own implementation of heatmap with additional information. Which data should decide about color of heatmap? What is more, matplotlib also doesn't support such solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- the 3 additional arrays can be compressed into 2D array of strings
- this can then be assigned to the **text** property
- finally update **hovertemplate** to display

```
xg = np.random.rand(100, 1200)

data_a = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
data_b = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
data_c = np.random.rand(100, 1200)

fig = px.imshow(xg, aspect="auto",color_continuous_scale='ice', )

fig = fig.update_traces(text=np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: ",".join(a.astype(str)), 0, [data_a,data_b,data_c]),
                       hovertemplate='x: %{x}<br>y: %{y}<br>color: %{z}<extra>%{text}</extra>')
```